# Non-ARC implementation Query

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Apple document Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide state that -

["a 'parent' object should maintain strong references to its 'children', and that the children should have weak references to their parents"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810)

Implementation of this is understood while using ARC. How am I supposed to implement it when I am not using ARC.

Comment: Strong = retain, weak = assign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent object should retain the child object. Child object should only be having assign relation to parent.